# Android VideoView crashing

Tags: android, memory, crash, android-videoview

I have an app that streams RTSP on 2.2 and HLS on 3.2, and I'm having the same problem with both. Any time from about 45 minutes to 3 hours of playing it will crash. You can notice the lag on the 2.2 really easily for awhile before it crashes. Now I'm trying to clear memory, not have any objects active other than what I need, but I still get these crashes regardless. Has anyone got any idea on how to stop it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you mention the Log cat Error then only we can find the problem then you reduce the size of video view

Comment: There isn't one. The video simply hangs, but the audio keeps playing. Also when i do this using fullscreen (I have a fullscreen activity that launches with just a videoview that is the size of the screen), I can exit that activity, to return to my main activity, but then cannot  click anything, but the video plays in the main activity still.